# common-lisp higher-order logical or function

Tags: common-lisp, logical-operators, higher-order-functions

I often have a `truth-list` like the following `'(nil nil nil t nil t nil nil nil)` and I would like to call `(reduce #'or truth-list)`

However, this does not work and I found that `or` is a macro. Is there a quick and easy way I can get this to work like a function? What I have been doing is passing: `(lambda (p q) (or p q))` as my function, but since I have come across this so many times, I bet there is a better way.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really. You actually need the function. Just define a `BINARY-OR` function. If you use it often, then just add it to your code.

Alternatives:

```
(some #'identity '(nil nil nil t nil t nil nil nil))
```

or

```
(loop for i in '(nil nil nil t nil t nil nil nil) thereis i)
```

Bonus: both above forms will stop at the first *true* value. The `reduce` variant won't.

Comment: Or (position-if-not #'null list) - truly there are many options.

Comment: @Xach: How about `find-if-not`? We don't need the index.

Comment: or `(member-if 'identity list)` which also stops at the first true value *and* gives you a way to get it and be able to find the remaining values.